# How do I save survivor Jose?

Tags: dead-island

I came across a survivor in the south bunker on the first resort map.  I think his name is Jose. I can't seem to get him to talk to me once I kill the zombies outside the fence that are trying to get him. Basically I have no idea how to save him or get to the 'portal'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [Jose Garcia](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Jose_Garcia).  You'll have to kill 2 Thugs and 4 Walkers that are right outside the fence before he'll talk to you.

[Some people](http://www.deadislandforums.com/showthread.php/1547-Jose-Garcia-Side-Mission) have reported that occasionally one or more of the zombies might glitch and end up inside the fence where you can't kill them.  If you haven't killed 6 zombies, look around a bit, and then try saving and resetting the game to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the exact problem I've been having two zombies glitched inside the fence and I couldn't kill them. Thanks again I appreciate it! :)